# cache html page at app loading

Tags: iphone, html, caching, uiwebview

Is it possible to cache a html page at `applicationDidFinishLauchingOptions()` method so that when I want to implement `UIWebView` the delay taken for loading that html page can be avoided?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the data at the time of loading of app itself, and then convert that to `NSString` or keep that as `NSData`. After that later when you want to load the page you use like -

For `NSString` -

```
 NSString *htmlString =  // string content
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURLString];
```

for `NSData` -

```
NSData *htmlData = // data content
[webView loadData: MIMEType:@"" textEncodingName:@"" baseURL:@""];
```

Comment: this is not working i tried to implement using folllowing code
in appdelete.h in applicationDidFinishLaunchingOptions()

    NSURL *req1=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"A" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO];
    htmltemp= [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:req1];

and in my view controller at viewWillAppear()

    url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"A" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO];
    [newdemo loadData:appDelegate.htmltemp MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:url1];

any help?

Comment: try converting nsdata into nsstring and then use loadHTMLString method. Also try logging nsstring value to see what it actually has?

Comment: uiwebview does shows html page but after long delay which i want to avoid in first place itself any way thanks for replay and showing a new approach towards this problem, right now trying to save html in plist and then showing at required place.